# Is there a clever trick to translating a DNAStringSet in R?

Tags: r

The following summarizes my code which does generate a large DNAStringSet:

```
library("BSgenome")  
library("Biostrings")
library ("BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38")
ls("package:BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38")
genome <- BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38
seqinfo(genome)
df0<- read.csv("s",header=TRUE,sep=",",stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
skip=0)`
df1 <- as.data.frame(df0$Gene)
names(df1) <- (c("Gene"))
df2 <- df1 %>% separate(Gene, c("Chr","start", "stop", "direction"), 
":")
df3 <- cbind(df1, df2) 
df3$Chr <- sub("^", "chr", df3$Chr )
df3$ntseq <- getSeq(genome, df3$Chr, start=as.integer(df3$start), 
end=as.integer(df3$stop))
ntseqs <- DNAStringSet(df3$ntseq)
aaseqs <- translate(ntseqs, genetic.code=GENETIC_CODE, 
no.init.codon="TRUE", if.fuzzy.codon="X")
```

I get the following error:

Error in translate(ntseqs, genetic.code = GENETIC_CODE, no.init.codon = "TRUE",  :    unused arguments (genetic.code = GENETIC_CODE, no.init.codon = "TRUE", if.fuzzy.codon = "X")**

Comment: You should consider making this example more reproducable by not depending on some arbitrary csv file on your file system called 's'. First I would check the `ntseqs` is one of the classes that works with `translate()` in the documentation. I can't be of much help past that without a reproducible example.